# parseFromString returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, domparser

My parseFromString returns 'undefined', neither '<parsererror…' nor parsed xml!

I can´t find the reason. Can you help, please?

```
var parser = new DOMParser(), // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser
    _sourceDOC = null;    
alert('_sourceXML: "' + _sourceXML.innerHTML + '"'); // returns string with xml source :-)
_sourceDOC = parser.parseFromString(_sourceXML.innerHTML,"text/xml");
alert('parseFromString: ' + _sourceDOC.xml); // returns 'undefined', neither '<parsererror…' nor parsed xml!
```

The first alert:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/axASd.png

PS: On the other hand, this works as expected. But I use Firefox 17 and don't want to use ActiveX.

```
var xmlDocIE = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.6.0");
xmlDocIE.async = false;
xmlDocIE.loadXML(_sourceXML.innerHTML);
```

**PPS: Solution:**

```
var parser = new DOMParser(),
    _sourceDOC = null,
    serializer = new XMLSerializer (),
_sourceDOC = parser.parseFromString(_sourceXML.innerHTML,"text/xml");
str = serializer.serializeToString (_sourceDOC);
alert('parseFromString: ' + str); // Result as expecded! :-)
```

As a consequence, I replaced the wrong code (resultDoc.xml) in my script:

```
_destination.innerHTML = resultDoc.xml;
```

by the correct code, and it works fine:

```
_destination.replaceChild(resultDoc, _destination.childNodes[0]);
```

Thanks, user1279647!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this property is only for IE (http://help.dottoro.com/ljhwhicc.php). Maybe you should use  `XMLSerializer`